# RKHS and the Kernel Trick seen in Machine Learning

Tags: functional-analysis, machine-learning, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

So I have been reading about Reproducible Kernel Hilbert Spaces (RKHS), and I am confused with how people use it in regards to the kernel trick seen in Machine Learning.

For example, in [this blog post](https://ngilshie.github.io/jekyll/update/2018/02/01/RKHS.html#the-kernel-trick) (Section 4.), they provide an example saying that they define the map $\phi:\mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathcal{H}$ to be $\phi(x) = K_x$ where $K_x$ is the reproducing kernel of the element $x \in \mathcal{X}$.

And then we have the kernel function:

$$K(x,z) = \langle \phi(x), \phi(z)\rangle_{\mathcal{H}}$$

Ok so far, I understand this as the "feature map" is a map from the set $\mathcal{X}$ to the hilbert space of functions $\mathcal{H}$.

However, in the example they provide, further down in section 4, they define $\phi(x)$ has a a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{10}$. This confuses me, as I thought that $\phi(x)$ should be an element of the hilbert space of functions $\mathcal{H}$ and not a vector.

Is it because, the vector represents a function by some linear combination of functions?

Comment: Yes, your guess is right.  In the example, they're taking $\mathcal{X} = \mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathcal{H}$ to be the Hilbert space of polynomial functions in $3$ variables of degree $\leq 2$, which is $10$-dimensional.  So, while elements of $\mathcal{H}$ are polynomial functions, they can be represented as vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{10}$ (after choosing a basis for $\mathcal{H}$).

Comment: Of course there's nothing special about $10$ here.  In general, if $\mathcal{H}$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space (e.g., every RKHS is a vector space), then by choosing a basis of $\mathcal{H}$, elements of $\mathcal{H}$ can be represented as vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. So given the degree 2 polynomial kernel, as it is a kernel we know there exists a RKHS such that the kernel is given by its reproducing kernel. But, why can we then rewrite the kernel $K(x,y) = \langle k_x, k_y \rangle_{\mathcal{H}}$ as an inner product in $\mathbb{R}^{10}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That blog post uses (imo) ambiguous notations and terminology, so I totally understand your confusion.

The short answer is that the definition given in that blog post is **wrong** : for a given kernel $K$, a [feature map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space#Feature_maps) $\varphi$ is a map from $\mathcal X$ to **any** Hilbert space $F$ (called a feature space) such that the following relation holds :
$$K(x,y)=\langle\varphi(x),\varphi(y) \rangle_F \ \  \text{for all } x,y\in \mathcal X \tag1 $$
In particular, observe that **$F$ needs not be equal to $\mathcal H$**.  (In fact, there always exist infinitely many feature maps and feature spaces for a given kernel $K$)

When we use the kernel trick to solve problems in practice, we don't really care about the feature map itself : the whole point of using kernel methods is that we can implicitly perform computations in $\mathcal X$ while implicitly using the higher dimensional representations in $F$.

Feature maps are however useful as they tell us the dimensionality of the space $F$ in which the computations are implicitly performed (and we know that more dimensions implies more representation power).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is starting to make more sense. But why can we write that: Given a kernel $K(x,y)$ $\; \exists \; \phi: \mathcal{X} \rightarrow F$ such that $K(x,y) = \langle \phi(x), \phi(y) \rangle_{F}$ . Is this related to Mercer's theorem?

Comment: As so far from my knowledge of RKHS and Moore' Theorem we can only say that given a kernel $K(x,y)$ there exists a RKHS such that $K(x,y) = \langle k_x, k_y \rangle_{\mathcal{H}}$ . Where $k_x$ is a reproducing kernel of the element $x$.

Comment: Well, a "trivial" feature map which is always guaranteed to exist is  $\varphi : x \mapsto K(x,\cdot)\in\mathcal H$. Similarly, since for most practical cases, the RKHS $\mathcal H$ [is separable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4648348), it is isomorphic to $\ell^2$ and you could thus find a feature map $\phi : \mathcal X \to \ell^2$ which represents $K$. So yes, there always exist feature maps, but the "most relevant" ones are the ones with feature space of least dimension, since they tell us how expressive the RKHS associated with $K$ is.

Comment: Ok thanks again that makes sense, so there exists multiple possible feature maps that give the same kernel, but a single unique RKHS. I was wondering if you knew anything about Mercer's theorem and how it relates to this topic, does it help with finding such feature maps that give the kernel?

Comment: Yeah, Mercer's theorem is intimately related to kernel methods and the idea of implictly lifting the input space $\mathcal X$ to a feature space $F$. You should have a look at [this blog post](https://gregorygundersen.com/blog/2019/12/10/kernel-trick/) by Gregory Gundersen to learn further about this.